# How do I elegantly discard a friend?

Tags: relationships

I have a friend who I have been meeting every Sunday to communicate process in learning and job for a year.

About 2 months ago, he lost his enthusiasm for improvement. He is not providing new resources or insights and is just asking me for my new insights or my recommended books, movies, music etc. without any feedback in the next meeting.

We noticed the situation and he played tricks to meet every other week by saying he had a temporary task to do on Sunday.

I decided to break off the relationship completely to save my time a month ago.

He lives nearby and I often encounter him. How do I drop the friendship elegantly?

Comment: "I believe that in the morning you'll begin to see the light" - http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/paul-simon/50-ways-to-leave-your-lover-7bda7e68.html You're asking how to do something that is being  done to you. Let it happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds very much as though this is what he's trying to do to you - distance himself.

So, you just let these scheduled meetings slip, you form some other plans so that you don't have to have them, and make your ah-hoc encounters a casual Hi/Bye type of thing.

If he wants to continue with the structured meetings, it up to him to bring some commitment to the party.

Comment: Yes, he is playing a naive trick by pretending not caring the value our meeting provided and does not confront with the fact he is becoming a purely consumer instead of a supplier.When he appoints me, I am not willing to refuse with that trick.It's too obvious and seems stringy.

Comment: @Yumi So the only value in friendship you have is that one thing? I don't see why you're being so difficult about it then, clearly you don't consider him a friend. It doens't look like he cares that much either.

Comment: Your comment values a lot @Sidar

Comment: @Yumi I don't follow. You decided to completely break off the relationship but you seem to imply it hasn't? The way you describe friend here is more like an acquaintance. If you have broken off the "relationship" why are you asking for validation though? The only logical solution here is to stop caring and stop chasing it. The guy is actively trying to avoid your meetup.